# Karma is not running any service test, only components

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I created a service where it can house logic shared by multiple components. Attempting to write unit tests for it but when I run `ng test`, it only runs the component spec files. Even when I use `fdescribe` in the `*.service.spec.ts` file, it seems to ignore it.

Previously, this wasn't a problem.

I've checked all configurations, double checked spelling, wrote failing test cases, etc.

**testing-file.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestingFileService {

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Function to test
   */
  runTest(): string{
      return 'Testing'
    }
}
```

**testing-file.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('TestingFileService', () => {
    let service: TestingFileService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
        service = TestBed.inject(ScheduleValidationService);
    });
    
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should run test', () => {

    const result = service.runTest();

    expect(result).toMatch('Testing');

  });
}
```

***karma.conf.js***

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/[app-name]'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 8080,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

EDIT 3/24 - Added test.ts file:

***test.ts***

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

//First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.component\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Comment: could you also provide your '/src/test.ts' file

Comment: Sure, just added. Looking at it, could it be the `context`?

Comment: This is the regex of the stock CLI:  `const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`. Try this one, it should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.component\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

explicitly selects all your files with extension `.component.spec.ts`. try another regex to select all test files
`/\.spec\.ts$/`, not just all the "component" tests